# Build Configuration for Telerik Appbuilder Mobile App other than Debug,Release mode (need for dev,stag,preprod)

Tags: cordova, telerik, environment-variables, buildconfiguration, telerik-appbuilder

I am using telerik appbuilder to create my mobile app and i need seperate configurations for various environments.So i referred [Build Configurations](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/cordova/build-configurations/overview) and how to [Create Environment Settings](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/cordova/build-configurations/application-settings).But these two ariticles fully dealing with debug and release mode.

In the article they instructed that

> When you create the application settings file, AppBuilder adds a *.debug.json and *.release.json to your app. In your code, reference the* .debug.json or ***.release.json** file as *.json only. During build operations, AppBuilder automatically uses the JSON file that corresponds to the currently selected build configuration.

During build app builder have debug or release mode:
[image: Build mode debug/release]

But i need to have more environment build configuration for various environment variables for dev,stag,preprod.
How to create environment variables for Dev,Stag,Preprod in telerik appbuilder mobile App?

Comment: As of today (January 2016) you are limited to Dev and Prod environments for our build configurations. There are plans to introduce custom environments as we get into 2016.

Comment: @RobLauer do you know how to test for If in #DEBUG# via javascript or is that not possible within the cordova app?

Comment: If you are testing in the simulator, you can check for `window.navigator.simulator === true` for debugging purposes. Otherwise I don't believe you can check the state other than using build configs.